# insertion went wrong 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: python, mysql

Insertion went wrong `1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;` check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'%d,%d,%d)'` at line 1

```
sql =""" INSERT INTO carprice(carmodel, mileage,sell_price,age) VALUES (%s,%d,%d,%d)"""
for x in list(csvdata('carprice.csv')):
cur.execute(sql,(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3])) 
con.commit()
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question, follow community guidelines and edit it in accordance? Thanks!

Comment: @CodeIt see this please i'm getting TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: @LazyCoder please check

Comment: @CodeIt thanks allot my mileage col data is in string format i need to convert that to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the arguments,

```
 cur.execute(sql,(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]))
```

You need to use `%` sign in order to pass arguments.

```
 cur.execute(sql%(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]))
```

*EDIT*:

To fix [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239540/insertion-went-wrong-1064-42000-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax#comment100980723_57239540) error posted in the comment section. You need to check whether you are passing integer value. If you need to convert string value to integer, you can use the below code.

```
cur.execute(sql%(x[0],int(x[1]),int(x[2]),int(x[3])))
```